# Repeated ERROR: NoneType in Sanic App

Tags: python, sanic

I keep getting `Error: Nonetype` from a Sanic app and I cannot identify the reason.

My code:

```
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import json, text
from sanic.request import RequestParameters

from parse_data import ParseData

pdata = ParseData()
app = Sanic('sanic_sms')

app = Sanic(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["POST",])
async def test(request):
        data = {}
        if request.form:
                data = request.form
        elif request.json:
                data = request.json

        result = pdata.prepare_output(data.get('text'))

        resp = json(result)
        resp.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
        resp.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "Content-Type,Authorization"
        return resp

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8002)
```

> 2017-05-13 15:10:03,454: INFO: Goin' Fast @ http://0.0.0.0:8002
>   2017-05-13 15:10:03,456: INFO: Starting worker [30662] 2017-05-13
>   15:11:19,579: ERROR: NoneType

How can I solve this?

Comment: You'll have to find out where `ERROR: NoneType` originates, so probably in the source code of Sanic (maybe use a debugger to help with that). Or ask the developers why they are not giving proper information about an error.

Comment: Add `debug=True` to `app.run` to get more details. Is the `parse_data` a package available through `pip`? I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

It was probably some bug in some previous version of Sanic (I got that behavior on version 0.4.0).

The app threw `NoneType 408` at a constant rate.
Solved it by tempering the `KEEP_ALIVE` setting of the `Config` dictionary:

```
from sanic.config import Config

Config.KEEP_ALIVE = False
app = Sanic(__name__)
```

In the current version (0.7.0) this seems to have been fixed.